# How to ask for only Date in Google Assistant actionSdk

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am using DateTime intent to get DOB of user and my Google Assistant actionSdk code is as below

```
// Actions SDK
const app = actionssdk()

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', conv => {
  conv.ask(new DateTime({
    prompts: {
      initial: 'When do you want to come in?',
      date: 'What is your Birth Date?',
      time: 'What time of day works best for you?',
    }
  }))
})

app.intent('actions.intent.DATETIME', (conv, input, datetime) => {
  const { month, day } = datetime.date
  const { hours, minutes } = datetime.time
  conv.close(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: 'Great see you at your appointment!',
    text: `Great, we will see you on ${month}/${day} at ${hours} ${minutes || ''}`
  }))
})
```

Its working fine and able to get Date but its force to get time as well. but as my requirement i have ask only for Date. if i remove time or initial key them its giving error.

Comment: What about just using the date portions of the structure and ignoring the time portion?

Comment: No possible because it ask user for date and time, we want date of birth not date of time